# Having Trouble Importing Database, #1064 Database Error

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?php

return array

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => 'mysql',
' at line 1
```

I'm trying to import a Database for a site, can anyone tell me where is the irregularity in this database.

Comment: You have a problem with your script next to the code that mysql is telling you about. Search for that code in your mysql script and check what is wrong. To get a complete ansewr post the sql of the relevant part of the script.

Comment: Are you trying to run php code as SQL?

Comment: <?php

return array(

 'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
 'default' => 'mysql',






 'connections' => array(

  //**ENTER YOUR MYSQL INFORMATION HERE**//